# Find closest match JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dataset, pattern-matching

I have a JSON dataset,

```
{
 "a": ["73.0", "41.0", "98.0", "43.0"],
 "s": ["74.0", "43.0", "112.0", "44.0"],
 "f": ["75.0", "45.0", "116.0", "45.0"],
 "l": ["76.0", "47.0", "120.0", "46.0"],
 "x": ["77.0", "49.0", "128.0", "47.0"],
 "q": ["78.0", "51.0", "134.0", "48.0"]
}
```

I want to closest match with a test data e.g. below, closest match is the array in the dataset which has lowest average difference related to the test array. In this example the closest match is  "a": ["73.0", "41.0", "98.0", "43.0"],

```
{
 "t": ["75.0", "42.0", "100.0", "44.0"]
}
```

Any library which can help with this? btw doing in JS.

Comment: How do you define "closest"? Make an array of the object properties, then sort it based on your closeness criteria. The first element of the result will be the closest match.

Comment: By _closest match_, do you mean **with the most values that are strictly equal** or something like **with the lowest average difference between corresponding properties**?

Comment: Yes, lowest average difference between corresponding properties.

Comment: Say you compare 1 and 10, 9 difference, but 900% difference.  Then compare 91 and 100, same 9 difference but 9% difference.  Just think about whether relative difference is more important than numeric distance.

Comment: James, thanks but here numerical difference is important.

Comment: I was doing it in old fashion way, summing all elements in an array and then absolute difference with the sum of elements in the test array. lowest value is closet. But I think Jeffrey did it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on the assumption that:

- Your json is parsed and *normalized* so that all array values are **numbers**
- You intend to measure *difference* in absolute numbers: `diff(a, b) => Math.abs(a - b)`
- You want to find the **key** of the property pointing to the array that matches closest

```js
// We're gonna get the closest match from here
const parsedJson = {
    a: [73, 41, 98, 43],
    s: [74, 43, 112, 44],
    f: [75, 45, 116, 45],
    l: [76, 47, 120, 46],
    x: [77, 49, 128, 47],
    q: [78, 51, 134, 48],
};

// We're gonna find the closest match to this
const comparator = [75, 42, 100, 44];

// Gets the average value of all given numbers
const avg = (...numbers) => numbers.reduce((acc, n) => acc + n, 0) / numbers.length;

// Returns an array with the absolute numeric difference
// between corresponding indices within 2 given arrays of
// numbers.
const difference = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.map((num, i) => Math.abs(num - arr2[i]));

// Returns the key of source that contains the array that
// matches closest to predicate.
const closestMatch = (comparator, source) => {

    const [keyOfClosestMatch] = Object
        .keys(source)
        .map(key => [key, avg(...difference(comparator, source[key]))] )
        .reduce((lowestSoFar, nextPredicate) => {
        return lowestSoFar[1] < nextPredicate[1]
            ? lowestSoFar
            : nextPredicate;
    });

    return keyOfClosestMatch;
}

let closestKey = closestMatch(comparator, parsedJson);
document.body.innerText = `Closest: "${closestKey}": [${parsedJson[closestKey]}]`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the keys and the items and check the absolute difference for taking the closest value for the result array.

```js
var data = { a: ["73.0", "41.0", "98.0", "43.0"], s: ["74.0", "43.0", "112.0", "44.0"], f: ["75.0", "45.0", "116.0", "45.0"], l: ["76.0", "47.0", "120.0", "46.0"], x: ["77.0", "49.0", "128.0", "47.0"], q: ["78.0", "51.0", "134.0", "48.0"] },
    test = ["75.0", "42.0", "100.0", "44.0"],
    result = Object.keys(data).reduce(function (r, k, j) {
        data[k].forEach(function (a, i) {
            if (!j || Math.abs(a - test[i]) < Math.abs(r[i] - test[i])) {
                r[i] = a;
            }
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```